# java.lang.NullPointerException when call to a method is made

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when `sendToAll(name)` is called.

```
public clientThreader(Socket cliSocket)
{
    try
    {
        outSocket = cliSocket;
        readStream = new ObjectInputStream(outSocket.getInputStream());
        String name = (String)readStream.readObject();
        totConnected++;
        clientNames.add(name);
        System.out.println(name+" is connected");

        if(name!=null)
            sendToAll(name);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Fail here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It does not enter the method called and results in this output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at chatServer.sendToAll(chatServer.java:60)
    at chatServer.access$200(chatServer.java:5)
    at chatServer$clientThreader.<init>(chatServer.java:110)
    at chatServer.setUpServer(chatServer.java:44)
    at chatServer.start(chatServer.java:29)
    at chatServer.main(chatServer.java:14)
```

I do not understand what is the reason Im getting this exception.

**EDIT**: Line 60 is the statement `allCli.equals(null)` below:

```
private void sendToAll(String newCli)
{
    for( ObjectOutputStream allCli : clientOutStreams)
    {
        if(!(allCli.equals(null))) //line 60
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("here");
                allCli.writeObject(newCli);
                System.out.println("here");
            }
            catch(Exception sendFail)
            {
                System.out.println("SendToAll Failed");
                sendFail.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have NPE on 60 line of chatServer class. What is on that line?

Comment: We need to see the line 60 of ``chatServer``. It is some line inside the ``sendToAll`` method.

Comment: added line 60 to the ques

Comment: allCli object is null

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(!(allCli.equals(null)))` to `if(allCli != null)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition from `!(allCli.equals(null))` to `allCli != null`. The reason you are getting a `NullPointerException` is because a `null` object does not have an `.equals` method that you can call.